# Windows Application : using Unity vs using WPF

Tags: xml, wpf, user-interface, networking

Hello and thank to everyone is going to give me an answer.

I have just received a project in which i have basically to receive from different TCP/IP sockets, XML files, reading them and converting in other formats and, after the processing has ended, sending them to different destination.

Basically, there is already an application that actually DOES what it is requested by me. The fact is that its interface is really NOT user-friendly and i wanted to improve a lot that aspect. For this reason i started to think of using Unity, since it will allow me to use some "fancy" features and maybe some animation with ease, without becoming mad with learning WPF (since i dont know it so deeply)

I useda lot UNITY and i love the UGUI system. So i'm asking you if it is actually possible to use Unity for this kind of application and, moreover, what i need to do to reduce the performance used.

Comment: sure it is possible.. I just dont see the point of using unity for conversion tasks

Comment: @xyLe_ What do you suggest?

Comment: If you want to use C# and dont like WPF, you can still just use WinForms (In my opinion it is a bit more straightforward to use than wpf). What kind of "fancy" features are you thinking of?

Comment: if i need to semplify everything what i really need is dragging objects and drawing connector lines between them.

Comment: So maybe using WinForms is a good idea in this case. It is a little bit easier than WPF (in my opinion) and developing things you want to have shouldn't be a challenge. However, if you want to provide advanced user interface with animations or something similar I would recommend to do it with WPF

Comment: I really would like to continue developing with WPF, but it looks so slow when implementing template controls! Maybe it's me that I dont know a faster way. For this reason i wanted to use Unity because it's really fast to provide resources under the prefabs objects...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has no connection to this web site. You are looking for **gamedev.com**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF is amazing and Unity UI is too. **Both are excellent at what you need**.

On the one hand, Unity is a game engine and that means that you would have a ton of unused stuff if you make your project with Unity, and therefore, the project size would increase a lot.

Also have in mind the initialization time. Unity will take extra time against a simple WPF application when loading.

On the other side, you can target more platforms with Unity out of the box.

I worked with both WPF and Unity and if I were you, I would do it in WPF.